# Adding a dataframe column using an existing column and its corresponding list values

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df`.

```
V1  V2 V3
A   1  3
A   2  8
B   4  12
C   3  2
R   8  9
```

I also have a list `lst` that works as a map, I can pass a string as an index to the list and it will return a string value. E.g.

```
lst[["A"]] => "AB"
lst[["B"]] => "BA"
lst[["C"]] => "FE"
lst[["R"]] => "WE"
```

What I want is to create a new column for `df` in relation to an existing column. The first column in `df` will work as the key index to the list and it will return in the same row in the new column the respective value.

I would like to end up with:

```
V1 V2 V3  V4
A  1  3   AB
A  2  8   AB
B  4  12  BA
C  3  2   FE
R  8  9   WE
```

Also I want to avoid for-loops since my actual data is very large and also because I would like to see a different and elegant solution.
Is there a way to do the above?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: When you create examples (especially in the `r` tag) please always create your data in a reproducible, runnable way. That means we should be able to copy, paste and run the code to create your example data and see the example code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dat = read.table("clipboard", header = TRUE)

lst = list("AB", "BA", "FE", "WE")
names(lst) = c("A", "B", "C", "R")

dat$V4 = lst[dat$V1]

> dat
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  A  1  3 AB
2  A  2  8 AB
3  B  4 12 BA
4  C  3  2 FE
5  R  8  9 WE
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I was using instead double brackets: dat$V4 <- lst[[dat$V1]]. Could you please explain the difference and why it works with single brackets? Thank you

Comment: @user159941 glad it works. There is a pretty detailed response on that at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/the-difference-between-and-notations-for-accessing-the-elements-of-a-lis

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`:

```
df%>%mutate(V4=lst[V1])

#  V1 V2 V3 V4
#1  A  1  3 AB
#2  A  2  8 AB
#3  B  4 12 BA
#4  C  3  2 FE
#5  R  8  9 WE
```